# How to alter the Views field Format drop-down menu

Tags: 7, views, entities, files, media

I am exporting some XML feeds using Views. One of these fields needs to look like this:

```
<image>http://example.com/path/to/myimage.jpg</image>
```

I am storing my image in a CCK field. When selecting that field in Views, these are the options provided:

[image]

I don't need an teaser, full node, editable something, or HTML formatted link, just the path to the image. How do we alter that **Format** selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your content type is blog, for example, and it has a CCK image field, create a relationship from your blog content type to the image content type.

Create a new field in the View and select the field_image from the image content type, make 
sure to select the relationship you created:

[image]

And select URL to file from the Format dropdown:

[image]

Comment: http://content.screencast.com/users/tony.rallen/folders/Jing/media/1dc2c7d9-be46-48c3-aba0-a04c319460c4/2011-04-08_1914.png: description, title and alt text. There's no URL link there.

Comment: @amateur barista I overlooked the fact that you were adding a node reference to your image.

Comment: I also forgot to mention it.